# Write an ini key with name of variable value

Tags: node.js, ini

I am trying to create an ini-database for every user that typed /boot (something).
But the problem is that I cannot write to ini. I need to do that:

Write into an ini section "boots" a key with a name of value of variable bootuserid. This is what I tried:

```
boots.'${bootuserid}'

boots.$bootuserid

boots.${bootuserid}

boots.(bootuserid)
```

All the scripts failed. So how do I make an ini key name of a value of variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bracket notation to access a variable name with another variable:

`boots[bootuserid]`

I.e.

```
a={b:1}
myvar="b"
a[myvar] //returns 1
```